# how can i slideDown A Hidden element from 0 opacity to 1 with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, opacity, slidedown

i have a coke like below that using jquery prototype Library:

```
        new Effect.SlideDown(this.imageDataContainer, { sync: true, duration: this.resizeDuration, from: 0.0, to: 1.0 }), 
        new Effect.Appear(this.imageDataContainer, { sync: true, duration: this.resizeDuration })
```

this code force the imageDataContainer element to sliding Down From 0 Opacity To 1 Opacity.

how can i implement upper codes with new downloaded jquery library from jquery.com web site?

the syntax of slideDown is like this :
[http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_slidedown.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_slidedown.as)

i know how slideDown And fadeTo Functions Work in jquery / but how can i combine them like the upper codes?

i test the below code - but u can not changing the opacity -*-**DURING**-*- toggle :

```
          $('#lightbox-container-image-data-box').animate({
            opacity: 0,
            height: 'toggle',
            opacity: 1
          }, 400, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
```

thanks 4 attention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for that. With animate you can animate any arbitrary number of properties on an element.

Check a demo of the code below here: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisramakers/8ewEp/

```
$('#book').hide();
$('#book').animate({
  opacity: 'toggle',
  height: 'toggle'
});
```

Comment: thanks 4 answer / but i want to change the opacity of #book from 0 to 1 -_-DURING-_- toggle / not at start and end toggle / how can i do that ?

Comment: @LostLord I'm pretty sure the answer given animates both properties at the same time. Did you look at the jsfiddle example?

Comment: you should just initially hide it then, and as far as i can see the opacity change is happening during the toggle. I've slowed down the effect on the demo page to show it.